# Fill a fixed-size dataframe with null values in between valid data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I have a sensor that measures data every ~60seconds. There is a little bit of delay between calls, so the data might look like this:

```
timestamp, value
12:01:45, 100
12:02:50, 90
12:03:55, 87
              # 12:04 missing
12:05:00, 91
```

I only need precision to the **minute**, not seconds. Since this gathers data all day long, there should be 1440 entries (1440 minutes per day), however, there are *some* missing `timestamp`s.

I'm loading this into a `pd.DataFrame`, and I'd like to have 1440 rows no matter what. How could I squeeze in `None` values to any missing timestamps?

```
timestamp, value
12:01:45, 100
12:02:50, 90
12:03:55, 87
12:04:00, None  # Squeezed in a None value
12:05:00, 91
```

Additionally, some data is missing for several HOURS, but I'd still like to fill those with `None`.

Ultimately, I wish to plot the data using `matplotlib`, with the x-axis ranging between (0, 1440), and the y-axis ranging between (0, 100).

Comment: `asfreq` maybe?

Comment: 1. You do not need to fill the missing data to plot with matplotlib, just make sure to use a timedelta/datetime type for x, 2. If you really want to fill, set `timestamp` as index and use `reindex` with a custom list of the times you want (check [`timedelta_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.timedelta_range.html))

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Resampler.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) if need replace only values between first and last timestamp:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.resample('1min', on='timestamp').first()
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].fillna(df.index.to_series())
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
            timestamp  value
0 2021-09-20 12:01:45  100.0
1 2021-09-20 12:02:50   90.0
2 2021-09-20 12:03:55   87.0
3 2021-09-20 12:04:00    NaN
4 2021-09-20 12:05:00   91.0
```

If need all datetimes per day add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.resample('1min', on='timestamp').first()

rng = pd.date_range('00:00:00','23:59:00', freq='Min')
df = df.reindex(rng)
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].fillna(df.index.to_series())

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
               timestamp  value
0    2021-09-20 00:00:00    NaN
1    2021-09-20 00:01:00    NaN
2    2021-09-20 00:02:00    NaN
3    2021-09-20 00:03:00    NaN
4    2021-09-20 00:04:00    NaN
                 ...    ...
1435 2021-09-20 23:55:00    NaN
1436 2021-09-20 23:56:00    NaN
1437 2021-09-20 23:57:00    NaN
1438 2021-09-20 23:58:00    NaN
1439 2021-09-20 23:59:00    NaN

[1440 rows x 2 columns]
```